# should I Check or Uncheck "Unrestricted web access" in iTunes Connect, if my app contains admob ads?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, rating-system, admob

I was trying to submit my updated version of app for review. The problem is, I have included **Admob Ads** (Google Mobile Ads SDK) in this build. will it affect my app ratings? i already have 4+ ratings for my app. i have a dilemma whether to check or uncheck **Unrestricted web access** in the ratings section. it goes between 4+ and 17+ ..

Comment: if you used the ***Ads framework***, then you need to enable the ***Check mark*** for serve the ads

Comment: you need to check it if you use webview and allow user to type in any URL. This is important if your app is designed for kids. For admob you don't need to check unrestricted web access as it doesn't allow to type in any URL within your application. refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462543/what-does-unrestricted-web-access-mean-in-itunes-connect